# Compare rows in SQL Server in same table (or different tables with same structure)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, compare

I know this is a quite general question but I would like to know the options in SQL or other external tools to compare some rows in the same SQL table or in 2 tables that have the same structure.

The tables contain a high number of columns (60)

For example let's suppose we have 2 different rows with the same ID and similar data.

When comparing 2, is it possible that in the results we just the the different item between those rows?

For example:

```
Table : Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 ....(until column 60)  
Row 1 : AAA  BBB  CCC  DDD  EEE  
Row 2 : AAA  BBB  CCC  DDD  DDD
```

The result should return that there is a difference in Col5, but the others are the same.

As I mentioned, this is a  quite open topic, but I would like to know your suggestions.

Comment: This is not standard database functionality.  You can, of course, write a query for any two given tables.

Comment: You could combine code that creates comma-delimited strings with `case` expressions that compare the fields and report appropriately.

Comment: You do know that will be a lot of comparisons?  N(N-1)/2

Comment: If my answer sorted you out, can you please click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use external tools for this. One such tool is RedGate Data Compare. It is a paid one but you can try for 14 days.

[Link to Redgate Data Compare](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/index)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out the "[EXCEPT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)" operator. Except shows the difference between two tables. The results will be records from the first table.

```
SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
  ( 1, 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE')
, ( 2, 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE')
, ( 3, 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE')
, ( 4, 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'DDD')
) tbl ([ID], [Column2], [Column3], [Column4], [Column5], [Column6]) 
EXCEPT
SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
  ( 1, 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE')
, ( 2, 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE')
, ( 3, 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE')
, ( 4, 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE')
) tbl ([ID], [Column2], [Column3], [Column4], [Column5], [Column6])
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=88f555db5a022504689ed75c61ca494c)

[image: results]

Or you can do a left join to the same table.

```
;WITH
source_data
AS
(
    SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
      ( 1, 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE')
    , ( 2, 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE')
    , ( 3, 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE')
    , ( 4, 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'DDD')
    , ( 1, 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE')
    , ( 2, 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE')
    , ( 3, 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE')
    , ( 4, 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE')
    ) tbl ([ID], [Column2], [Column3], [Column4], [Column5], [Column6]) 
)
SELECT 
    tbl1.* 
FROM
    source_data AS tbl1
    LEFT JOIN source_data AS tbl2 ON tbl1.[ID] = tbl2.[ID]
WHERE 
    1=1
    AND 
    (
    tbl1.[Column2] != tbl2.[Column2]
    OR tbl1.[Column3] != tbl2.[Column3]
    OR tbl1.[Column4] != tbl2.[Column4]
    OR tbl1.[Column5] != tbl2.[Column5]
    OR tbl1.[Column6] != tbl2.[Column6]
    )
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1f44d23d2a6b3a18528b7cf6be660e0c)

[image: results]